# how to restore moved <li> element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
const list = document.querySelector("#List");
const list2 = document.querySelector("#List2");

list.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const LI = ev.target.closest("li");
  list2.append(LI);
});
```

```html
<ul id="List">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>


<ul id="List2"></ul>
```

this code above basically will move an `<li>` element to another `<ul>`, and i want to create a function that will restore the moved `<li>` back to the original `<ul>` in its original index. so for example when i move this list `<li>3</li>` i want the function to place it back at the original index in the first `<ul>`, in this case it will be placed at the third index which is in the middle of `<li>2</li>` and `<li>4</li>`

how can i achieve this?

Comment: What if `<li>2</li>` was also moved before restoring `<li>3</li>`? What have you tried so far? Is there a code snippet you can share with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach. I handle everything in a single click handler function. At first I "remember" the initial position each `LI` had in the first `UL`. When a click happens I simply transfer the `LI` to the "other" `UL`. Then, if the click happened within the second `UL` (`if (!idx) ...`), I rearrange the elements in the first `UL` again by sorting them and re-inserting them into the `UL`.

```js
const lists = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul.pickable")];
[...lists[0].children].forEach((li,i)=>li.dataset.n=i); // remember original order

document.addEventListener("click", ev => {
  const LI = ev.target.closest("li");
  if (LI?.parentNode.classList.contains("pickable")) { // only, if the click happened within a `LI` element ...
    const idx=lists.indexOf(LI.parentNode),
          UL = lists[1-idx];
    UL.append(LI);
    if (idx) [...UL.children].sort((a,b)=>a.dataset.n-b.dataset.n)
                             .forEach(li=>UL.append(li))
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="pickable">
  <li>this</li>
  <li>order</li>
  <li>should</li>
  <li>be</li>
  <li>kept</li>
</ul>


<ul class="pickable"></ul>
```

I could simply leave out the `if (idx)` if I wanted the `LI`s to be sorted *in both* `UL`s in the "original" order.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to remember some information about where you got it. There are a few options:

- If you're only ever going to move *one* `li`, you could remember its `nextSibling` element, and then use `insertBefore` on the list, passing that `nextSibling` reference for the "reference element." But if you were also going to move other elements, that might not work because the sibling after it may not be there anymore.
- If you want to do it by *index*, you need to remember what the element's position in its parent was. I don't think the DOM gives you a direct way to get that information, but you can find it easily enough by applying `Array.prototype.indexOf` to the parent's `children` collection.
- Have the elements in an order we can determine from their contents (they have such an order in the question), and insert the element where it should be in that order. No need to remember anything special because it carries its contents with it.

Here's an example of the index approach, since you mentioned that in the question; see comments:

```js
const list = document.querySelector("#List");
const list2 = document.querySelector("#List2");

list.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    const li = ev.target.closest("li");
    // Find its index in its parent's `children` collection
    const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(li.parentElement.children, li);
    // Save that as an attribute
    li.setAttribute("data-index", index);
    list2.append(li);
});

list2.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
    const li = ev.target.closest("li");
    // Get the index, if it has one
    let index = +li.getAttribute("data-index");
    // Add at the end if no index or it's out of range
    const maxIndex = list.children.length;
    if (isNaN(index) || index > maxIndex) {
        index = maxIndex;
    }
    // Get the element that will be after it
    const nextSibling = list.children[index] || null;
    // Insert before it (if `nextSibling` is `null`, inserts at the end)
    list.insertBefore(li, nextSibling);
    li.removeAttribute("data-index");
});
```

```html
<ul id="List">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="List2"></ul>
```

Comment: This does not always work reliably. The position of each `LI` element is taken only when it is clicked. By that time it might have shifted to the top already. Click through the example and you will notice yourself. (Start by clicking on the top items first.)

Comment: @cars10m - That's true, I didn't claim it was a be-all, end-all; more a starting point. Your approach of remembering all of the initial indexes is a good alternative. I think if I were doing this, though, I'd use some natural order to the elements based on their content (my third option above).

Comment: @cars10m hmm yeah i just realised several problems will happen if i do it using indexes